# SSAS Cube Modelling Fact or Dimension - No Additive Columns

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cube, powerpivot, olap-cube

Im pretty new to BI modelling and have been assigned a project to create a BI solution for a Patient Administration System (millions of rows).  There are no sales or additive information in the system.  Basically all of the Measures will be Counts.  Im finding it difficult to locate good examples/tutorials of the model I require as most BI implementations seem to be based around Sales.

If anyone could help with my modelling problem I would be very grateful.

Tables (columns excluded for brevity) within the implementation are

```
Patient (
    Key -> Surrogate Key
    PatientId -> Source System Id
    Name -> Text
    AgeKey -> FK to Age Dimension Table
    NationalityKey -> FK to Nationality Dimension Table
    DateOfBirthKey -> FK to Date Dimension Table
    GenderKey -> FK to Gender Dimension Table
    etc.
)

Referral (
    Key -> Surrogate Key
    ReferralId -> Source System Id
    PatientKey -> FK to PatientTable
    ReferredAtDateKey -> FK to Date Dimension Table
    PriorityKey -> FK to Priority Dimension Table
    SpecialtyKey -> FK to Specialty Dimension Table
    etc
)

WaitingList(
    Key -> Surrogate Key
    WaitingListId -> Source System Id
    ReferralKey -> FK to ReferralTable
    AddedToListDateKey -> FK to Date Dimension Table
    RemovedFromListDateKey -> FK to Date Dimension Table
    StatusKey -> FK to Waiting List Status Table
    Position -> int
    etc
)
```

I need to be able to build reports/charts around Patients, Referrals and Waiting Lists so I am using Views to create my Fact tables in SSAS.  Examples are:

```
FactPatient (
    Key -> Surrogate Key
    PatientId -> Source System Id
    Name -> Text
    AgeKey -> FK to Age Dimension Table
    NationalityKey -> FK to Nationality Dimension Table
    DateOfBirthKey -> FK to Date Dimension Table
    GenderKey -> FK to Gender Dimension Table
    etc.
)

FactReferral (
    Key -> Surrogate Key
    ReferralId -> Source System Id
    -- Patient
    Name -> Text
    AgeKey -> FK to Age Dimension Table
    NationalityKey -> FK to Nationality Dimension Table
    DateOfBirthKey -> FK to Date Dimension Table
    GenderKey -> FK to Gender Dimension Table
    etc.
    -- Referral
    ReferredAtDateKey -> FK to Date Dimension Table
    PriorityKey -> FK to Priority Dimension Table
    SpecialtyKey -> FK to Specialty Dimension Table
    etc
)

FactWaitingList(
    Key -> Surrogate Key
    WaitingListId -> Source System Id
    -- Patient
    Name -> Text
    AgeKey -> FK to Age Dimension Table
    NationalityKey -> FK to Nationality Dimension Table
    DateOfBirthKey -> FK to Date Dimension Table
    GenderKey -> FK to Gender Dimension Table
    etc
    -- Referral
    ReferredAtDateKey -> FK to Date Dimension Table
    PriorityKey -> FK to Priority Dimension Table
    SpecialtyKey -> FK to Specialty Dimension Table
    etc
    -- Waiting List
    AddedToListDateKey -> FK to Date Dimension Table
    RemovedFromListDateKey -> FK to Date Dimension Table
    StatusKey -> FK to Waiting List Status Table
    Position -> int
    etc
)
```

As you can see I am attempting to keep to the Star schema here as I am including the Foreign Keys/Relationships to Dimension tables for related objects e.g. FactReferral has all of the FactPatient relationships.

Is this the right way to model this? Or should I be using a Snowflake schema with FactReferral just having a relationship to FactPatient?

Should I create an extra denormalized Dimension for Patient with no relationships and then create a relationship between it and FactReferral?  e.g.

```
DimPatient (
    Key -> Surrogate Key
    PatientId -> Source System Id
    Name -> Text
    Age-> int
    Nationality -> Text
    DateOfBirth -> Date
    GenderKey -> Text
    etc.
)

FactReferral (
    Key -> Surrogate Key
    ReferralId -> Source System Id
    -- Patient
    PatientKey -> FK to Patient Dimension Table
    -- Referral
    ReferredAtDateKey -> FK to Date Dimension Table
    PriorityKey -> FK to Priority Dimension Table
    SpecialtyKey -> FK to Specialty Dimension Table
    etc
)
```

Ultimately Im not really sure how to model the one-to-many relationship tree.  There are other tables that are related to Referral such as Assessment and Attendance that I have excluded from my description but I have the same problem with.

Any help or suggestions would be most welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1728036-17-1.aspx

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/FindPost1728079.aspx

Answer provided by PB_BI

> I don't think that you need a "FactPatient" table in your underlying
>   data since it looks like it's entirely dimensional. Rather, when it
>   comes to creating your cube, use the Patient dimension table to create
>   a measure group that has a factual relationship to the patient
>   dimension (for counts and such). Then your FactReferral and
>   FactWaitingList tables will only need to have 1 foreign key to the
>   Patient dimension (and not all of the patient-specific ones such as
>   NationalityKey etc.).

I followed the advice and created a denormalized view DimPatients and added this to my data source view. iwas then able to add a relationship to this from FactReferral -> PatientKey.

After this I created a Dimension based on the DimPatients View and was able to add all of the Columns in DimPatients as Attributes for the dimension.  This made them Queryable.

The last thing I did was add a Measure Group for the DimPatient dimension which enabled me to perform Queries against the Patient data

Hope this helps someone else some day

Matt